# How can i disable multitasking/app switch, when our application is running?

Tags: android, android-homebutton

Our app crashes when we hold the home button (to get into the app list).
`KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH` does not work for us.

Comment: How is your app crashing (logcat would be nice)? Shouldn't your app *not* crash?

Comment: Multitasking happens differently depending on the phone you are using, some (like Galaxy devices) have a home button that needs to be held, others have a specific button so this might be difficult to control. You should probably avoid manipulating Android behavior like that

Comment: well, the programmer is currently afk (i am designer)
i dunno what kind of crash is it, do you guys know any solution for disabling the "App switch" window, so if someone holds home button, it does nothing ? this is what i am looking for

Comment: It says "app has stopped"

Comment: Disabling the HOME button is very bad practice, but you could set in your manifest a HOME Activity, and every time the HOME button is pressed it will redirect to that Activity. Simply have that Activity redirect you back into the app. To the user it would be as though the Home button is doing nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the keycode for multitasking/appswitch for samsung galaxy s3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554207/what-is-the-keycode-for-multitasking-appswitch-for-samsung-galaxy-s3)