# What is the keycode for multitasking/appswitch for samsung galaxy s3?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, keycode, android-homebutton, samsung-galaxy

Our app is crashing (it says "application has stopped) after we longpress the home button on samsung galaxy s3 (the longpress button is used to popup the multitasking screen/app switch dialog)
we do not have this problem on our another testing device htc evo 3d
so what is the keycode for this "action" ? and how can we disable this function ?

This code sadly does not work:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH) {
        System.exit(0);
            return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to do that (hopefully it is not possible).  Don't try to disable basic Android functionality, rather fix the actual problem in your code causing your crash.

Comment: and do you know where might be the problem ?

Comment: No, because I don't have you app.  Collect a stack trace of the failure, and rewrite your question to be about solving the problem indicated there.

Comment: Most probably your app is crashing when it is entering the onPause(), you should check the logcat, stacktrace, publish them here, as this might happen on other devices. Disabling a standard OS functionality is not a solution.